# Windows Metro App, Hammer.js and Knockout.js - Can't swipe to next page

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate, hammer.js

Trying to panleft and right to change pages in a winjs metro app. Currently getting the following erorr:

Unhandled exception at line 112, column 4 in ms-appx://7d6d13c7-6e98-48fd-aff4-70283c269088/js/jquery.validate.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'form' of undefined or null reference

I have placed some validation to check if form data is entered using jQuery validate. To enable the swipe feature I need to go to each individual page and then swipe otherwise the app just crashes. I'm able to go to each page when I click a button but swipe doesn't work.

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');

            // create a simple instance
            // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
            var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

            // let the pan gesture support all directions.
            // this will block the vertical scrolling on a touch-device while on the element
            mc.get('pan').set({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL });

            // listen to events...
            mc.on("panleft panright panup pandown tap press", function (ev) {
                if (ev.type == "panleft") {
                    if ($("form#mortgageDetails").valid()) {
                        WinJS.Navigation.navigate('/pages/overpayments/overpayments.html');
                    }
                }
            });

HTML Mark Up

  <section class="page-section" aria-label="Main content" role="main">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <form id="mortgageDetails">
                    <div id="applicantDetails">
                        <div id="alertLbl" class="win-error"></div>

                        <label>Loan Amount *</label> <input type="text" data-rule-number="true" data-rule-required="true" name="loanamount" id="loanamount" data-bind="value: MortgageDetail.LoanAmount" /> <!--onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"-->
                        <span class="field-validation-valid error" data-valmsg-for="loanamount" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        <label>Loan Term In Years *</label><input type="text" data-rule-number="true" data-rule-required="true" name="loanterminyears" id="loanterminyears" data-bind="value: MortgageDetail.LoanTermInYears" />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid error" data-valmsg-for="loanterm" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        <label>Annual Interest Rate *</label> <input type="text" name="annualinterestrate" id="annualinterestrate" data-bind="value: MortgageDetail.AnnualInterestRate, uniquename:true" /> <br />
                        <span class="field-validation-valid error" data-valmsg-for="annualinterestrate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

                        <label>Monthly Payment Amount </label>£<span id="monthlypaymentamount" data-bind="text: MortgageDetail.MonthlyPaymentAmount"></span> <br />
                        <!--<p><a class="navLink" href="/pages/overpayments/overpayments.html">Overpayments</a></p>-->
                        <div style="width:280px; ">
                            <input type="submit" id="btnOverpayments" value="Overpayments" style="margin-top: 5px; float:right;">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div id="myElement"> </div>
        </section>
```

When the error occurs it takes me to the following page jQuery validate page to this location

```
valid: function() {
    var valid, validator;

    if ( $( this[ 0 ] ).is( "form" ) ) {
        valid = this.validate().form();
    } else {
        valid = true;
        validator = $( this[ 0 ].form ).validate();
        this.each( function() {
            valid = validator.element( this ) && valid;
        });
    }
    return valid;
},
```

Comment: You're going to have to show the code that reproduces the issue.  See the error message:  `Unable to get property 'form' of undefined or null reference`.  Now show us how you've initialized the jQuery Validate plugin using `.validate()` along with the relevant HTML markup for the `form`.

Comment: **We don't need to see any code that's inside the plugin**.  We only need to see _your_ code, and I don't see where you've properly _initialized_ the jQuery Validate plugin.  Where is _your_ call to `.validate()`?  Check out the wiki page for a basic demo:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info

Comment: Do you think thats the issue to stop me from swiping for pages until I click on the individual page access them then able to swipe?

Comment: I'm addressing the JS error you're reporting and I still have not seen your call to `.validate()`.  In order to use this plugin, you have to initialize it by attaching the `.validate()` method to your form.  Again, please click the link I gave you and look at the demo.

Comment: In my example I have it as .valid I think this is the wrong way so I'm trying to make amendments and improve my code. Thanks :-)

Comment: You cannot use the `.valid()` method without first initializing the plugin with the `.validate()` method.  That's your whole problem and the source of your JS error.  Refer to the example code at the link I gave you.

Comment: Thanks you were right! Silly mistake off mine but I learnt something new today. Thank you for explaining this :-)

Comment: I posted an answer below so you can "accept" it, thereby closing out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/) without first initializing the plugin with [the `.validate()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/). That's your whole problem and the source of your JavaScript error.

Refer to the [example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-validate/info).